# pig tagsource doesnt work with multiple files

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig script that loads multiple input files.  When I want to get the input filename with each input record from the file `tagsource` or `tagfile`, it only pickups the first filename but includes the data from both files.

**Example**:

```
I_STREAM = LOAD '/tmp/' USING PigStorage(';','-tagFile') AS (filename, f1, f2, f3);
DUMP I_STREAM;
```

**Contents of Files**:

```
/tmp$ cat ./file1.txt
1;1;1 

/tmp$ cat ./file2.txt
2;2;2
```

**Current Output**:

```
(file1.txt, 1,1,1)
(file1.txt, 2,2,2)
```

**Expected Output**:

```
(file1.txt, 1,1,1)
(file2.txt, 2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because your files are small, and they're being combined?
Documentation specifies to set "pig.splitCombination" to false.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html